# Necessary condition for have same rank

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $P,Q$ real $n\times n$ matrices  such that $P^2=P$ , $Q^2=Q$ and $I-P-Q$ is an invertible matrix.

Prove that $P$ and $Q$ have the same rank.

Some help with this please , happy year and thanks.

Comment: well i really stuck in this problem, usually i write my work but really is hard to me.

Comment: I dont know if this helps but I guess if $I-A$ is invertible then $A$ is nilpotent... I am trying in that way... try your best

Comment: thanks i will ctry your hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $I-P-Q$ is invertible by assumption, we have 
$$rank(P)=rank(P(I-P-Q))\mbox{ and }rank(Q)=rank((I-P-Q)Q).$$
On the other hand, we have 
$$P(I-P-Q)=P-P^2-PQ=-PQ$$
since $P^2=P$, and 
$$(I-P-Q)Q=Q-PQ-Q^2=-PQ$$
since $Q^2=Q$. Combining all these, we have
$$rank(P)=rank(-PQ)=rank(Q).$$

Comment: really really tahnxs i understand it

Answer (score 3):

Let $V$ be the vector space on which all these matrices act. First, note that $V = P(V) \oplus (I-P)V$ (and in fact, $P(V) = \ker (I-P),$ $(I-P)V = \ker P.$ Similarly for $Q$ instead of $P.$

Now, notice that the third condition states that for no vector is it true that $(I-P)v = Q v.$ This means that $\dim Q (V) \leq \dim P(V).$ But by a symmetric argument, $\dim P(V) \leq \dim Q(V).$ So, $\dim Q(V) = \dim P(V).$ Now the result follows, since the rank of $P$ (or $Q$) is equal to the dimension of the image.